# Dictionary re-adding words as new keys instead of increasing value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am writing a program that finds every unique word in a text and prints it in a text box. I do this by printing each key in a dictionary however my dictionary is adding each word as a separate key instead of ignoring words that are already there.

The function is being called correctly and it does work it simpy prints the entire text I hand it however.

EDIT: I am reading the string from a text file then sending it to the function.
This is the input string and the output:

**Output**:

> To be or not to that is the question Whether tis nobler in mind suffer
>   The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune Or take arms against a sea
>   troubles And by opposing end them die sleep No more sleep say we end
>   The heartache thousand natural shocks That flesh heir Tis consummation

```
public string FindUniqueWords(string text)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    string uniqueWord = "";
    text = text.Replace(",", ""); //Just cleaning up a bit
    text = text.Replace(".", ""); //Just cleaning up a bit
    string[] arr = text.Split(' '); //Create an array of words

    foreach (string word in arr) //let's loop over the words
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word)) //if it's in the dictionary
            dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + 1; //Increment the count
        else
            dictionary[word] = 1; //put it in the dictionary with a count 1
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in dictionary) //loop through the dictionary
    {
        uniqueWord += (pair.Key + " ");
    }
    uniqueWords.Text = uniqueWord;
    return ("");
}
```

Comment: wouldnt be LINQ and a Distinct() a much easier way?

Comment: Code looks good. Did you use the debugger with a very simple eaxmple like "one two two three"?

Comment: Add the input string sample and the result  to make it more clear

Comment: U can use HashSet instead of dictionary, check for ContainsKey and simple do nothing if true

Comment: I tried your code and it works well. But I think you have to add empty string check, because if your initial string contains two or more combined spaces, result will contain empty string as well.

Comment: @DrKoch I used a shakespear poem

Comment: Check your original Keys for spaces/linebreaks/escape characters and repost them here.

Comment: Use `string.Split()` (no arguments) this will split at newlines and tabs as well.

Comment: "use the debugger" was a suggestion, not a question

Comment: IMHO, LINQ's `Distinct()` is a better way to do this (though you may want to use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`). But for future reference: you should look into the `TryGetValue()` method on the dictionary object (more efficient than doing the key/value lookup twice), as well as learn to use `StringBuilder` for any string concatenation that occurs in a loop (especially where the data could be long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the text with `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`, so `text` may also contain newline characters.

Replace `arr = text.Split(' ')` by `arr = text.Split(' ', '\r', '\n')` or add another replace: `text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");`

Of course, by looking at `arr` in the debugger, you could have found out by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way: (Dont forget to use Using System.Linq)

```
    string strInput = "TEST TEST Text 123";
    var words = strInput.Split().Distinct();                
    foreach (var word in words )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem with your code. And I am using System.Linq()

Comment: This example doesnt seperate lower & upercase - is that your problem - can you provide a sample inputtext

Comment: I have checked and that is not the problem and check my question again to see the input I use

Comment: how do you handle the assignment to the textbox - you just return "" in your sample - and i also cannot see where you assign the words to a textbox

Answer (score -1):

Your code works as it's supposed to (ignoring case though). The problem almost certainly lies with showing the results in your application, or with how you are calling the `FindUniqueWords` method (not the complete text at once).

Also, pretty important to note here: a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` by default simply **cannot** contain a single key multiple times. It would defeat the whole purpose of the dictionary in the first place. It's only possible if you override the `Equality` comparison somewhere, which you aren't doing.

If I try your code, with the following input:

> To be or not to that is is is is is is is the question

The output becomes :

> To be or not to that is the question

It works like it's supposed to.

Comment: Who is downvoting this and why?

Comment: The first sentence is the only important bit of this answer.

Comment: @Rawling true, but making such statements without providing evidence? I'd rather not call that an answer, such a statement is more fitting for a comment on the question itself.

Comment: The only reason your example works better than the question is that you've added "is is is is" not "is Is iS IS". The original code's problem is not how it displays or returns the results - it's wonky, but it's not wrong, and you changing it hasn't fixed the casing problem.

Comment: @pyrocumulus this is how I am getting the text and calling the code                                         string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathname");
            FindUniqueWords(text);                                                                             I think the error is there because when I use a string I just write in the code like you did it works fine

Comment: @Rawling he already stated that casing is not the problem. I do not need to solve a problem that the he does not have. Apart from that I have no idea what you are getting at. I provide a working sample that proves his code is okay so the cause is some external factor and I get downvoted. But an answer only stating 'your code is not the problem' would not get downvoted? Weirdness.

Comment: @Rawling I still don't get it, but based on your reputation I'll go with it. I have removed the sample code to only state my input sample.

Comment: @JulienPowell you do `text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText()`, then replace "." and "," and split on ' '. So your "words" may still contain newline characters. You should replace them with ' ' also.